# Why are Ashkenazi haftarahs longer than that of Sephardim?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, haftarah

A look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haftarah#List_of_Haftarot) confirms my suspicion that when Ashkenazim and Sephardim read the same haftarah, the Ashkenazim generally start earlier and/or finish later than that of Sephardim. Is there a specific reason why this is so?

Comment: it would help to answer if you asked about a specific haftorah there are specific reasons that haftorahs are read the way they are in specific communities and are not generalizations of longer vs shorter

Comment: @Dude Nearly every single case of variation has the Asheknazi one being longer. Specific cases won't cut it here.

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps give answers for some haftorah and see if there is a common point behind the individual reasons.

Answer (score 3):

The Shulchan Aruch in [סימן רפד - דיני הפטרה וברכותיה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_25.html#HtmpReportNum0042_L2) says that the Haftarah should be at least 21 verses long, unless the theme ends beforehand.

> **א** מַפְטִירִין  בַּנָּבִיא מֵעִנְיָנָהּ שֶׁל פָּרָשָׁה. וְאֵין פּוֹחֲתִין מִכ'' א פְּסוּקִים, אֶלָּא אִם כֵּן סָלִיק עִנְיָנָא בְּבָצִיר מֵהָכֵי‏

<sup>(3 verses for each of the 7 people (as a minimum) who read in the Torah. Be'er Heitev [ibid](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_25.html#HtmpReportNum0042_L2) and [Aruch Hashulchan](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0200_L2))</sup>

It would seem that different congregations had different ideas as to what belongs to the main theme of the Haftara.

A quick perusal of [your link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haftarah#List_of_Haftarot) shows that Sephardim have many Haftarot with fewer than 21 verses, and Ashkenazim have almost none of those.

It appears that Sefardim had a narrower definition of what can be included in a theme.

<sup>It's now left to somebody with spare time to analyze each case and explain how each congregation themed each Haftarah.</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure that's all. The Gemara approves of the topic break for Tzav but Ashkenazim still don't follow it